# Custom Item Templates in Visual C++ Express

Tags: visual-c++

I tried to add a custom item template to Visual C++ Express 2008, but failed. Is this even supported in the Express edition or did I probably make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Express version does not support extension. But the [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43653/Visual-C-Express-Custom-Wizard) promises to fill the gap.